# How to Install NginX + Flask + Webmin to my Raspberry pi?

Tags: python, web-server, server

I'm newbie to the Web server. I have never setup any server before.

I would like to write program in Python, HTML, Java Script and then put it into my raspberry pi and interact with it by using another computer in the same network with local network land.

Can anyone please help me. I knows very few about command line (I know basic things like app get , etc.) and would like to know how to install these (NginX + Flask + Webmin + SQlite) together and get it to run.

The Webmin for Raspberry pi is quite difficult to install if you have better option please tell me ^^

I have searched for many days and still don't have answer in this topic. It has only about Apache with Flask which is not what I want to do.

Comment: Welcome - This is indeed interesting but the format is to ask a simple question. This is more of a tutorial and does not the format of the Site. Just search for installing `nginx on raspberry` then `flask on raspberry` and you will get step by step guides. If you run into a specific problem please ask about that here then.

Comment: When you are looking for answers to questions like these, you'll find *more information* if you consider a *more general context*. There are hundreds of millions of linux systems in the world, a large % of which are Debian derived like raspbian, but not more than one or two million raspbian systems.  So if you go looking for people who've installed Webmin on raspbian, you'll be luck to find any who've posted on line about it.  But if you look for `webmin debian`, presto, you'll notice webmin have an official page about it: http://www.webmin.com/deb.html `webmin linux` will yield even more.

Answer (score 2):

Webmin can be quite a resource hog and, while very powerful, it might be overkill if you just want to get a quick working webserver environment.

I'd try to go for [vestaCP](http://www.vestacp.com).  It's quite easy to install ([just 2 commands](http://vestacp.com/#install)) and comes with apache, nginx, mysql, php, python etc.  It doesn't come however with sqlite, but I don't see why a simple `sudo apt-get install sqlite sqlite3` wouldn't work.

I haven't tried to install it on a Pi but I cannot see why it shouldn't work.

Don't be fooled by the fact vestaCP is less known compared to webmin.  I'm running it on a lot of webservers and am quite happy with its performance.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to webmin, if you are running a debian derived distro such as raspbian you can follow the instructions [here](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html).  The package you need to download is [this one](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin_1.660_all.deb).

Generally, you can't use a normal debian package on the pi, which is why raspbian exists -- it's debian wheezy re-compiled for the pi's obscure little processor.  However, webmin appears to be all perl and shell scripts; there are no binary pieces.  Since it doesn't need to be compiled in the first place, it doesn't require a special package just for the pi.

Comment: but The webmin dozen't support the nginx. So should I consider ISPconfig? http://www.ispconfig.org/page/home.html
or Ajenti ?
http://ajenti.org

installing NginX + Flask + ISPconfig to my Raspberry pi will it be too difficult because I have no experience about command line and do I need to write a lot of command line to integrate these thing? I don't know much about web server too t-t

Answer (score 0):

I had similar needs few months ago. I've written a little guide for my friends where is `nginx` covered.
Maybe you'll find some interesting informations [there](http://tutos.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)